# Why does the fetch of an api not work if I simply change the url of the api on my component

Tags: react-native, api, fetch-api

I a creating a simple reactive app. I have implemented a fetch from an open API and it all works fine.
But when I change the url of that api in the fetch to an api that needs an api key to access it stops working. I have my own api key and have followed the instructions on the api documentation.

This is the api:
https://calendarific.com/api-documentation

I have a Holidays Component and an App.js document.

If I use the coffee API in my component everything is displayed properly.
`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, FlatList, Center, NativeBaseProvider, Text } from "native-base";

export default function Holidays() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  //fetching the data from the API
  //data Hook willhold fetched data
  //loading hook will tell the user if the data is on its way
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("https://api.sampleapis.com/coffee/hot");
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(data);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <Box px={5} py={2} rounded="md" bg="primary.300" my={2}>
        {item.title}
      </Box>
    );

};


useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center flex={1}>
      <Box> Fetch API</Box>
        {loading && <Box>Loading..</Box>}
        {data && (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
  }`
```

However if I change the url in fetch to the following one I get an error on the console log.

`"curl 'https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=cb1e68dec32b35d42671b82368aaf2fab927556a' "`

The error is the one displayed here:

```
`**`VM79:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`**`
```

Comment: `"curl 'https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=API_KEY' "` is not an URL. It is a curl command. You should use `fetch('https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=API_KEY')` instead. Btw, congrats on leaking your API key :)

Comment: Thank you! Don't worry already did a reset on the api key, that one is no longer functional. Now it is not giving me the error, but it is not showing anything either like the other API I used.

Comment: "Not showing anything"? I am not sure what do you mean but I'd suggest inspecting the http response with the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: I printed the data on the console and it seems there is a missing required call paramenter 
meta
: 
code
: 
404
error_detail
: 
"Missing required call parameters. See https://calendarific.com/ for details."
error_type
: 
"call failed"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.